# Would the thermometer inside an evacuated blackbody hollow sphere show temperature change when we start to heat the sphere?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, temperature, gauss-law, vacuum

Would the thermometer inside an evacuated blackbody hollow sphere show temperature change  when we start to heat the sphere? Newton law states that an electric or gravitational field does not exist inside a shell that emits the field.Does this apply to thermal EM radiation in this question?

Comment: Sure works the other way with a hot filament inside a vacuum chamber. Black body radiation is, well, everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As I recall from the definition, a cavity inside a black body is in equilibrium. All points on the wall are at the same temperature, and all small segments of the wall emit radiation at the same rate as they absorb radiation.  Given time, a thermometer inside becomes part of that equilibrium and its reading will give the temperature of the walls.

Comment: Have I understood your answer correctly: Gravit.field inside of a shell is zero,electrost.field inside a shell is zero but this does not apply to EM-waves field...so the EM-wave field inside a shell is not zero as the thermometer increases its temperature to that of the walls?